# EF core FromSql custom property binding

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's assume I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Code { get; set; }
}
```

The property `Code` is not a column but calculated through SQL query.
I would like to bind the property `Code` to my `Person` type using the `FromSql` method.
Something like this:

```
var result = db.Person
                 .FromSql("select Id, Name, 'Roar' as Code from Persons")
                 .Select(x => new Person
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Name = x.Name,
                     Code = EF.Property<string>(x, "Code")
                 }).ToList();
```

Is there any way to bind custom SQL query variable to object property?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with EF Core, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) say *"SQL queries can only be used to return entity types that are part of your model"* and that column is not part of your model.

Comment: came to same issue when I created geometry column and tried to map the calculated distance after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg). The dirty workaround for this was to remove `NotMapped` attribute.
However, to avoid removing `NotMapped` attribute, you can use a LINQ expression so that `code` gets its value.

Basically if you want to use complex custom SQL queries, the best way is to use ADO.NET.